# AngularJS Directives and Services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Evening all, i've created a directive to manage a search function that i want on my page - as you can see it is bound to 'scope.data', which allows me to pass data back to the page (whatever that is I chose an arbitrary collection of names here).

```
 .directive('ngSearch', function ($http, ProductService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { data: '=' },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.placeholder = attrs.placeholder ? attrs.placeholder : '';
            scope.search = function (searchString) {
                if (searchString.length > 1) {
                    ProductService.GetProductsByKeyword(searchString).then(function (result) {
                        scope.data = result.data;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    scope.data = [];
                }
            };
        },
        template:
            '<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-change="search(search.value)" ng-model="search.value" />'
    };
});
```

Now i'm considering how to call the service, as i see it have two options - add a controller directly to the directive, or actually doing the search within the directive in a service call.

By using the link function, the data is tightly bound to the directive:

```
<ng-search data="data"></ng-search>
```

...and i can understand why i'd do this for say, a search dropdown, but both ways kind of smell bad for linking a search box to a screen.

The question is - is it bad practice to call a service within a directive? Why should/shouldn't I?

Comment: No, it's not bad practice. But using a watch when you could use ng-change is a bad practice, though.

Comment: Good call and one that's duly noted; i understand why, i was originally doing a compare as i was testing the directive but removed it for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding service in directive itself & calling it from directive is not a bad practice. But the thing I really feel code smell is that you putted a `$watch` inside your directive that will watch on input field and will make service call.

Suppose user want to enter some search keyword like `angular` for that your directive will fire service call 5 times, that is looking hassy to me.

Instead of doing this I'd suggest you to use [**`ng-model-options`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) on that field with `debounce` set to some miliseconds like `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }` so that whenever user stops typic at that time only `ng-model` gets updated

**Template Input**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" 
  ng-model="search.value" 
  ng-model-options="{ debounce: 400 }/>
```

### When to use service directly inside directive/controller

Generally when we want directive to available a method to its child as an API kind of thing at that time we do add those method in directive controller & that service will get injected in controller function. In this approach any other directive which makes `require: '^ngSearch'` directive that will have an access to the `ngSearch` directive controller. And he can call that controller method from that child directive. In you case it doesn't seems like that case. You had defined all service related operation in `link` function. Also seems like no other directive will `require` this `ngSearch` directive thats why your current implementation looks cool.

**Note**

> Change your directive name, because your directive start with `ng`
>   keyword. Which could conflict with angular directive in future. Rename
>   it to customSearch would be better

Comment: i've amended the code accordingly, its the service element im most interested in, and why i should/shouldn't.

Comment: @NewZeroRiot did you look at my edit..? picture should be clearer now